# Any successful "dual license" OSS project I can use as template?

Tags: gpl, commercial

I'm rewriting my entire GPLv3 project in a different language to sidestep angry contributors that don't want me to make money on their contributions.

What I want for my project is:

- people can use it and contribute like GPL,
- if you want to embed it in some proprietary solution, you pay.

Basically it's an enforced donation to the project for whom intend to make money.

1. Is there a **standardised license** that fits my use case?
2. If not, is there an **existing project** you know of I can use as a template?

Comment: You would still need the permission of your angry contributors to change to a dual license.

Comment: I don't think so, they don't own the concepts, but just the implementation. Right?

Comment: Right.  If they contributed actual code they are joint copyright owners with you, but if they just sent you ideas to implement, then it's still only yours.

Comment: But if you translated some code, that would be a "derivative work" and the contributors of the original code would have copyright rights to your translated work.

Comment: FYI: The code achieves the same goals because I need to keep the same configuration file syntax. The architecture is heavily refactored and I wrote it in another language (Scala instead of Java). But you are right, I have no idea what the formal definition of "derived code" or "translated code" would be.

Comment: Whether A is a derivative of B is (in the U.S.) dependent on 2 factors (1) the author's access to original B and (2) A's similarity to original B. You can try to impose clean-room standards on yourself (i.e., don't look at the code while implementing, only look at requirements) but your familiarity with the code may make it impossible for you to completely diminish the access factor. How "similar" two works are for the similarity factor is subjective but can include non-literal aspects (using someone's fictional character in your new book is infringement, even without literal text copying)

Comment: That said, your self-description of the new work as "heavily refactored" is encouraging, and may be dissimilar enough to avoid infringement (but a court of law can tell you for sure, if you get sued). The fact that you're using a new language is less important (e.g., translations of natural-language literary works are still derivatives of the original)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As there are no "standard commercial" licenses (see also [Commercial licence deproliferation attempts](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/5558/commercial-licence-deproliferation-attempts/)), there is also no standard license combination for a OSS+Commercial dual license.

I know of at least one successful project that uses a OSS+Commercial dual license: [The Qt project](https://www.qt.io/licensing/).
From their licensing page:

> Qt for Application Development is dual-licensed under commercial and open source licenses. The commercial Qt license gives you the full rights to create and distribute software on your own terms without any open source license obligations. With the commercial license you also have access to the official Qt Support and close strategic relationship with The Qt Company to make sure your development goals are met.
>
> Qt for Application Development is also available under GPL and LGPLv3 open source licenses. [...] The Qt open source licensing is ideal for use cases such as open source projects with open source distribution, student/academic purposes, hobby projects, internal research projects without external distribution, or other projects where all (L)GPL obligations can be met.

---

When using a OSS+Commercial dual license, it is usually best to choose a copyleft license for the OSS side, because that ensures there is no (or less of a) loophole for commercial users to use the product without paying for the commercial license.

Comment: Good answer. Note that Qt was not proposed under LGPL before it was bought by Oracle, and thus the incentive to buy the commercial license was even greater.

Answer (score 1):

To your main question: **Any successful “dual license” OSS project I can use as template?**

I would argue: There are successful examples, but *you shouldn't use them as a template*.

The right license(s) and strategy for your project are very specific to your project and community. I strongly encourage you to choose your licenses based on what seems appropriate in your case, rather than which ones have seen success with other projects.

(The SFOSC project I'm involved with for example decided [the entire model](https://sfosc.org/business-models/dual-licensing/) doesn't align with it's principles)

---

Take for example [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/), which is arguably successful by several metrics.

Currently they dual license with their new [SSPL](https://www.mongodb.com/licensing/server-side-public-license) as a copyleft license for which they offer [commercial license](https://www.mongodb.com/commercial-license) alternatives as one aspect of their business model. (They also offer MongoDB as-a-service for example)

They created and [switched to this license](https://www.mongodb.com/press/mongodb-issues-new-server-side-public-license-for-mongodb-community-server) as a direct response to cloud providers making presumably large profits with their software and it sparked [heated discussions](https://www.zdnet.com/article/mongodb-open-source-server-side-public-license-rejected/) whether given the new restrictions the license can even be considered a free and open source software license. However it has been part of the apparently required pressure for [Google to negotiate a deal](https://www.geekwire.com/2019/google-cloud-makes-big-open-source-move-managed-databases-redis-labs-mongodb-elastic-coming-soon/) but also for [Amazon to make another hard fork](https://www.geekwire.com/2019/amazon-web-services-calls-mongodbs-licensing-bluff-documentdb-new-managed-database/).

Even if your project is in the exact same boat of this cloud providers vs database vendors clash of the titans, you'll have to ask yourself if you really want to take the same approach as MongoDB or your community has different values and concerns.

---

> Is there a standardised license that fits my use case?

Again, whether it fits your case is something you will need to decide with your community, but...

By definition, for dual-licensing you will want to select at least 2 software licenses. One for the OSS aspect, one as the commercial license you can buy.

Additionally you will need some type of [Contributor Agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contributor_License_Agreement) and have all contributors sign it. Specifically to make sure all copyrights are held by a single legal entity, which is necessary to be able to change the license without infringing on the copyrights of your contributors.

For the OSS license, there may be fitting candidates among the [copyleft](https://opensource.com/resources/what-is-copyleft) or [source available](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-available_software) licenses.

For CAs you might look at [Harmony agreements](http://www.harmonyagreements.org/overview.html) though I'm convinced there are more options out there.

And as talked about in [the previous answer](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/5634/15316) I'm not aware of any templates you can 'just use'.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to your question about whether there is an existing project that permits dual-licensing as GPL and as commercial:

The "gregbook" contribution to libpng is dual-licensed, GPLv2+ and BSD-like.
See the [LICENSE](https://github.com/glennrp/libpng/blob/libpng16/contrib/gregbook/LICENSE) file in libpng16's [contrib/gregbook](https://github.com/glennrp/libpng/tree/libpng16/contrib/gregbook) directory. "License 1" specifically permits commercial applications.

Comment: Oh that is an interesting application of double licensing. What I meant though is dual OSS+Commercial.

Comment: I believe that if you accept it under the BSD-like license you can use it in a commercial app and relicense it commercially, so long as you abide by the requirement to keep the BSD copyright notice intact.  The LICENSE says, "Permission is granted to anyone to use this software for any purpose, including commercial applications, and to alter it and redistribute  it freely, subject to the following restrictions:..."